# Light Privacy for Inside Mount Horizontal blinds

Tags: lighting, blinds, curtain-rail

I have Inside Mount Horizontal shades in my apartment. Currently there is light opening on the left and right side, causing light and privacy issues. Is there a way to cover these? Maybe install an

a) outside mount Roller Shades? Are roller shades able to pair up with inside mount horizontal shades, would it obstruct the pathway or look nice?

b) Curtains are another option, however I prefer option to be less visible, more discrete.

Are there any other good options?

Note: Apartment complex does allow screw mounting in drywall.

[image]

Comment: i would add boards, like 1x3s, flush and flat along the side to build up the walls. They can be painted to look right and poster puttied to retain w/o modification.

Comment: hi @dandavis do you have a google image or picture example? video? thanks

Comment: I can't envision, I am trying to do a google image search of what you wrote @dandavis

Comment: ascii art: old: `[===]`, new:  `[|===|]`, where `|` is a thin board, `=` are blinds, and `[` is the left side of the window.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Get the right size blind, not one that's too short.
- Hang curtains at either side.

Comment: if I installed roller shades on top, would that look right, or look kind of strange? Would it mess up with the path of my inside mount horizontal shades?

Comment: How it looks is decorating opinion, not functional advice, and thus off-topic here. Since I'm not suggesting roller shades, I have no particular opinion on those anyway.

Comment: I guess on a technical point, are there roller shades in the market which will not interfere with inside mount blinds?